# Glue Snail Shells to a wall

Tags: adhesives

Any recommendations on what type of glue I should use to glue snail shells vertically on a wall?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Alternatively, this is a duplicate of "[Type of adhesive to use to attach seashells to a frame already glued to a wall](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/5441)", which was closed as a duplicate of the question mentioned above. Does either of them help you, Claudia?